# How do I ensure that input is an integer with hasNextInt on Java

Tags: java, input

New programmer here. This is probably a really basic question, but it's stumping me nevertheless.
When I try to run this code on Eclipse, nothing happens. I'm trying to check for leap years. The input got to be an integer, if not, I want to keep repeating the loop (I'm trying to achieve this via the `input.hasNextInt` part). However, when I try to run it, nothing pops up at all, the console remains empty

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Leapyear {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int year;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Enter a year in numbers:");
        input.next();  
        }

        year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a year:");

        input.close();


        boolean is_leap = false;

        if (year % 4 == 0)
        {
            if (year % 100 == 0)
            {
                if (year % 400 == 0)
                    is_leap = true;
                else
                    is_leap = false;
            }
            else
                is_leap = true;
        }   
        else
            is_leap = false;

        if(is_leap)
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year!");
        else
            System.out.println(year + " is not leap year!");

    }

}
```

Comment: `hasNextInt` is a blocking call which is awaiting user input.

Comment: No it is not...

Comment: ``year = input.nextInt();`` need to be written before the call of next int.

Comment: just print something before the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to print the message once to see it in the console, otherwise, the message will only be displayed when the while loop is executed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year;
    System.out.println("Enter a year in numbers:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Enter a year in numbers:");
        input.next();
    }

    year = input.nextInt();
    //System.out.println("Enter a year:");

    input.close();


    boolean is_leap = false;

    if (year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if (year % 100 == 0)
        {
            if (year % 400 == 0)
                is_leap = true;
            else
                is_leap = false;
        }
        else
            is_leap = true;
    }
    else
        is_leap = false;

    if(is_leap)
        System.out.println(year + " is a leap year!");
    else
        System.out.println(year + " is not leap year!");

}
```